# Android: Fragment TabHost Icons cannot take up full space?

Tags: java, android, mobile, icons, android-tabhost

I've been messing with this for two days now and still can't seem to figure it out.

I''ve finally got the tabhost visible in all my activities however, in order to do so, I had to create a fragment activity. This messed up the layout of my tab buttons.  It worked perfectly when I was using tab activity but now, it looks like this:

[image]

I want the blue buttons to take up the entire bar. No background space like there is now. I don't know if it's a layout problem or scaling problem? Here is the code where I create the tabs and also where I size the tabe so that the middle one is twice as long as the outside tabs:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);


        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); //set the tab as per the saved state
        }

        // the following code is used to decrease the size of the two end tabs
                Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                int width = display.getWidth();

                TabHost mth = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

                mth.getTabWidget()
                        .getChildAt(0)
                        .setLayoutParams(
                                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width / 4,
                                        (int) (width / 4 * .625)));

                mth.getTabWidget()
                        .getChildAt(1)
                        .setLayoutParams(
                                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width / 2,
                                        (int) (width / 4 * .625)));
                mth.getTabWidget()
                        .getChildAt(2)
                        .setLayoutParams(
                                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width / 4,
                                        (int) (width / 4 * .625)));


    }

    /** (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); //save the tab selected
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    /**
     * Initialise the Tab Host
     */



    private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {


        mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        TabInfo tabInfo = null;

        Resources res = getResources();

        fragactivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_home)), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab1",ArrowsActivity.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        fragactivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_search)), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab2", OptionsActivity.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        fragactivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.twitter)), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab3", ArrowsActivity.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        // Default to first tab
        this.onTabChanged("Tab1");
        //
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);


        }

    /*
     * @param activity
     * @param tabHost
     * @param tabSpec
     * @param clss
     * @param args
     * */

    private static void addTab(fragactivity activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
        // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec
        tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

        // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
        // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
        // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
        tabInfo.fragment = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (tabInfo.fragment != null && !tabInfo.fragment.isDetached()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(tabInfo.fragment);
            ft.commit();
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }


        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}
```

This is the old code (When the buttons were sized properly.) It looks like the views were being passed through another .xml file that specified that the icon should match parent. I tried duplicating this in the new code but i think it's a little too complicated for me. Here's the code that worked along with the .xml:

```
private void setTabs() {

        // add tabs
        addTab("Home", R.drawable.tab_home, ArrowsActivity.class);
        addTab("Attendance", R.drawable.tab_search, OptionsActivity.class);
        addTab("@PSUStrength", R.drawable.twitter, OptionsActivity.class);
        // addTab("Contact Us", R.drawable.contact, OptionsActivity.class);
    }

    private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c) {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
        // TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
        // title.setText(labelId);

        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        // registerForContextMenu(icon);
        icon.setImageResource(drawableId);
        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

    }
```

tab_indicator.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="55dip"    
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"

    /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'd really appreciate some help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Has this problem been solved? I am actually facing somewhat similar one.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I had the same problem with text tabs, not images but I think the solution applies to both cases.

Inside the TabWidget there is a LinearLayout(View childAt in code below) for each Indicator you previously entered. This LinearLayout acts as a container for your Indicator's text/image. By default this LinearLayout has some padding. In my case this was 24. I just lowered it.

After adding the TabSpec instances to your TabHost enter following code

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
    View childAt = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
    childAt.setPadding(childAt.getPaddingLeft()/2,
        childAt.getPaddingTop(),
        childAt.getPaddingRight()/2,
        childAt.getPaddingBottom());
}
```

It would be good advice to keep this dynamic and that is why I give half of what was there before. If you set a fixed number you might have a problem with other(smaller) resolutions.

If you have text on your tabs you might want to manipulate it also. Do it like this:

```
        TextView tv = (TextView) childAt.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        //do whatever change in tv you might need, eg.
        tv.setSingleLine();
```